# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to MyClass

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am doing following

```
List<Campaign> campaigns = queryResultCampaign.getElements();
        
List<Campaign> campaigns = campaigns.stream().filter(campaign -> campaign.getCurrentStatus() !="deleted")
                .map(campaign -> (Campaign) campaign).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and get error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.banoent.eloquaapi.client.campaign.model.Campaign
```

I have almost tried everything over the weekend and no solution worked for me.

If I remove this streaming part from the code then everything works fine, I wanted to filter objects with certain status but then it started to give this error

```
@GetMapping(path = "/campaign/retrieve/list")
    public String retrieveCampaigns(@QueryParam(value = "offset") Integer offset,
                                    @QueryParam(value = "count") Integer count,
                                    @QueryParam(value = "page") Integer page,
                                    Model model,
                                    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                    HttpServletRequest request) {

        String site = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(EloquaApiConstants.SITE);
        String oauthError = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(EloquaApiConstants.OAUTH_ERROR);
        model.addAttribute(EloquaApiConstants.SITE, site);
        model.addAttribute(EloquaApiConstants.OAUTH_ERROR, oauthError);

        offset = offset == null ? 0 : offset;
        count = count == null ? recordsPerPage.get(0) : count;
        page = page == null ? 1 : page;

        CookieDefinition cookieDefinitionLoginDetails = CookieDefinition.builder()
                .cookies(request.getCookies())
                .cookiePrefix(CookiePrefix.SOURCE)
                .build();

        LoginDetails loginDetails = oauthService.createLoginDetails(cookieDefinitionLoginDetails);

        try {
            loginDetails = oauthService.verifyToken(loginDetails);
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            model.addAttribute(EloquaApiConstants.OAUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_ERROR, true);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(EloquaApiConstants.OAUTH_ERROR, false);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(EloquaApiConstants.OAUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_ERROR, true);
            return "redirect:/login/oauth/login-with-eloqua";
        }

        EloquaTaskQueryParameterDefinition countQueryParameterDefinition = EloquaTaskQueryParameterDefinition.builder()
                .eloquaTaskQueryParameter(EloquaTaskQueryParameter.COUNT)
                .eloquaTaskQueryParameterValue(count)
                .build();
        EloquaTaskQueryParameterDefinition depthParameterDefinition = EloquaTaskQueryParameterDefinition.builder()
                .eloquaTaskQueryParameter(EloquaTaskQueryParameter.DEPTH)
                .eloquaTaskQueryParameterValue("minimal")
                .build();
        EloquaTaskQueryParameterDefinition lastUpdatedParameterDefinition = EloquaTaskQueryParameterDefinition.builder()
                .eloquaTaskQueryParameter(EloquaTaskQueryParameter.LAST_UPDATED_AT)
                .eloquaTaskQueryParameterValue(0L)
                .build();
        EloquaTaskQueryParameterDefinition pageQueryParameterDefinition = EloquaTaskQueryParameterDefinition.builder()
                .eloquaTaskQueryParameter(EloquaTaskQueryParameter.PAGE)
                .eloquaTaskQueryParameterValue(page)
                .build();

        EloquaTaskDefinition taskDefinition = EloquaTaskDefinition.builder()
                .service(EloquaService.CAMPAIGN)
                .serviceType(QueryResult.class)
                .task(EloquaTask.RETRIEVE_MULTIPLE)
                .queryParametersDefinitions(Arrays.asList(countQueryParameterDefinition,
                        depthParameterDefinition,
                        lastUpdatedParameterDefinition,
                        pageQueryParameterDefinition))
                .credentials(loginDetails)
                .build();

        QueryResult<Campaign> queryResultCampaign = (QueryResult<Campaign>) taskService.executeTask(taskDefinition);
        List<Campaign> campaigns = queryResultCampaign.getElements();
        
        List<Campaign> collect = campaigns.stream().filter(campaign -> campaign.getCurrentStatus() !="deleted")
        .map(campaign -> (Campaign) campaign).collect(Collectors.toList());

        PaginationModel pager = PaginationViewHelper.getPaginationModel(queryResultCampaign.getTotal(),
                offset,
                count,
                page,
                recordsPerPage);

        model.addAttribute("paginationModel", pager);
        model.addAttribute("campaigns", campaigns);
        return CAMPAIGNS_RETRIEVE_CAMPAIGN;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
--Maria

Comment: you're providing wrong code, not the one that's causing the exception. you're probably using `@Controller` method, but you're not getting the arguments you think you're getting. please give the full controller method code, including class level annotations

Comment: That code does not make much sense right now. Additionally you need to google how to compare stings in java. Note that since filter knows the type because it can resolve `getCurrentStatus` I do not think there is a way that `map` suddenly needs a cast because it cannot infer `Campaign`.

Comment: this is the Error, I rechecked
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.banoent.eloquaapi.client.campaign.model.Campaign

Comment: @62mkv If I remove this streaming part from the code then everything works fine, I wanted to filter objects with certain status but then it started to give this error

Comment: Those two statements cannot be in your code as they are shown right there because they would redeclare `campaigns`. Show more context, where does `queryResultCampaign.getElements()` come from, does some casting happen there as well? How do the two snippets interact?

Comment: @maria so you say that "campaign" in the `.filter()` lambda is `Campaign` type, but in the `.map()` it's not ?? I don't believe it ) also, what would "work fine" here, without `stream()` call, as there's no code, essentially, without that call?

Comment: Both of you @62mkv , now I have added full controller in the question,

Comment: @luk2302 Its there now, full controller in the code.

Answer (score 0):

let's get rid of `Stream`-s then:

```
List<Campaign> filteredCompaigns = new ArrayList<>();

for (Campaign campaign: campaigns) {
  if (!campaign.getCurrentStatus().equals("deleted")) {
     filteredCompaigns.add(campaign);
  } 
}
/// use filteredCompaigns from here
```

Comment: I tried this solution too and it should have worked but it gives the same error

 *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.banoent.eloquaapi.client.campaign.model.Campaign
 com.banoent.eloquaapi.client.campaign.controller.CampaignControllerNew.retrieveCampaigns(CampaignControllerNew.java:132)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)*

Comment: and line 132 is for (Campaign campaign: campaigns) {

Comment: you see, the problem has nothing to do with `Stream`-s

Comment: the issue is here: 

```
QueryResult<Campaign> queryResultCampaign = (QueryResult<Campaign>) taskService.executeTask(taskDefinition);
List<Campaign> campaigns = queryResultCampaign.getElements();
```

Comment: it does not fail here because or RTTE, but when you try to cast elements, it fails. you need to look at the taskService.executeTask method

Comment: Spot on Problem was in executeTask Method and I have discussed it the developer who coded it, I have one more question, This works new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Campaign.class) but how we can .class with EloquaResult<Campaign> ? does not allow to add class infront ofQueryResult<Campaign>);

Answer (score 0):

ok, I fixed as follow, First from executeTask() returned json string initially I was returning Body.

```
    String jsonString = (String)taskService.executeTask(taskDefinition);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    QueryResult<Campaign> queryResultCampaign = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<QueryResult<Campaign>>() {});
    List<Campaign> campaigns = queryResultCampaign.getElements();
    campaigns = campaigns.stream().filter(campaign -> extracted(campaign)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```